# Application.GetSaveAsFilename - Autosave with VBA

Tags: vba, autosave

Application.GetSaveAsFilename - Autosave with VBA

Is it possible to save a file file without "save as dialog box"?

the file and name is generated after click on a button, now I need to save that file without "save as dialog box"

EDIT :
the question was NOT about saving excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Workbook.SaveAs`

For further information, check the following webpage:

[Workbook.SaveAs Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx)

**Syntax:**

*Workbook.SaveAs(FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)*

1. **FileName**: `DataType = String; Description = File Full Path; DefaultValue = ""`
2. **FileFormat**: `DataType = XlFileFormat; Description = File Extension;`
3. **Password**: `DataType = String; Description = Protection Password; DefaultValue = ""`
4. **WriteResPassword**: `DataType = String; Description = Write Reservation Password; DefaultValue = ""`
5. **ReadOnlyRecommended**: `DataType = Boolean; Description = Show Read-Only Recommended Message; DefaultValue = False`
6. **CreateBackup**: `DataType = Boolean; Description = Create Backup File; DefaultValue = False`
7. **AccessMode**: `DataType = XlSaveAsAccessMode; Description = Workbook Access Mode; DefaultValue = XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange`
8. **ConflictResolution**: `DataType = XlSaveConflictResolution; Description = Save Conflict Resolution; DefaultValue = XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution`
9. **AddToMru**: `DataType = Boolean; Description = Add to Recent Files; DefaultValue = False`
10. **TextCodepage**: `Description = Ignored for all languages in Microsoft Excel.`
11. **TextVisualLayout**: `Description = Ignored for all languages in Microsoft Excel.`
12. **Local**: `DataType = Boolean; Description = Saving Local Language; DefaultValue = False`